# How to compute `ulp`when `Math.ulp` is missing?

Tags: java, math, double, codenameone

I need the [ulp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) for a given double value, but since I am developing for Codename ONE, `ulp(double)` is not provided. Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to compute `ulp` in Java? Codename ONE provides just some of the methods in the `Math` class ([javadoc](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/java/lang/Math.html) for the CN1 version) and some of the gaps are filled in [MathUtil](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/util/MathUtil.html).

As a workaround, I use this (incorrect) code until I find a working replacement:

```
private double ulp(double y) {
    return y/1e15;
}
```

EDIT: I "rolled my own" and have just posted my code for [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52747/implementation-of-ulp-and-nextafter-for-platforms-where-these-are-missing). Just in case someone else needs this.

Comment: You can see how it's implemented in standard Java here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FpUtils.java#FpUtils.ulp%28double%29

Comment: Thank you. I was scared of by the `sun.*` package name when I first searched for this. I will have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, since I didn't find a working replacement (both Apache Harmony and OpenJDK end up using native methods that are not available on CN1), I wrote my own version (results tested against OpenJDK-version). Just in case anyone needs it.

As for codename One: I submitted a patch to the MathUtil class, so hopefully this will be added sooner or later.

```
/*
 * use a precalculated value for the ulp of Double.MAX_VALUE
 */
private static final double MAX_ULP = 1.9958403095347198E292;

/**
 * Returns the size of an ulp (units in the last place) of the argument.
 * @param d value whose ulp is to be returned
 * @return size of an ulp for the argument
 */
@Override
public double ulp(double d) {
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
        // If the argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative infinity, then the
        // result is positive infinity.
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    if (d == 0.0) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is Double.MIN_VALUE.
        return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    d = Math.abs(d);
    if (d == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        // If the argument is Double.MAX_VALUE, then the result is equal to 2^971.
        return MAX_ULP;
    }

    return nextAfter(d, Double.MAX_VALUE) - d;
}

@Override
public double copySign(double x, double y) {
    return com.codename1.util.MathUtil.copysign(x,y);
}

private boolean isSameSign(double x, double y) {
    return copySign(x, y) == x;
}

/**
 * Returns the next representable floating point number after the first
 * argument in the direction of the second argument.
 *
 * @param start starting value
 * @param direction value indicating which of the neighboring representable
 *  floating point number to return
 * @return The floating-point number next to {@code start} in the
 * direction of {@direction}.
 */
@Override
public double nextAfter(final double start, final double direction) {
    if (Double.isNaN(start) || Double.isNaN(direction)) {
        // If either argument is a NaN, then NaN is returned.
        return Double.NaN;
    }

    if (start == direction) {
        // If both arguments compare as equal the second argument is returned.
        return direction;
    }

    final double absStart = Math.abs(start);
    final double absDir = Math.abs(direction);
    final boolean toZero = !isSameSign(start, direction) || absDir < absStart;

    if (toZero) {
        // we are reducing the magnitude, going toward zero.
        if (absStart == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
            return copySign(0.0, start);
        }
        if (Double.isInfinite(absStart)) {
            return copySign(Double.MAX_VALUE, start);
        }
        return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absStart) - 1L), start);
    } else {
        // we are increasing the magnitude, toward +-Infinity
        if (start == 0.0) {
            return copySign(Double.MIN_VALUE, direction);
        }
        if (absStart == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
            return copySign(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, start);
        }
        return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absStart) + 1L), start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks! But the implementation of `copySign` is missing :(

Comment: @Thomas What platform are you on?

Comment: Trying to port this to Dart. Your code is calling `com.codename1.util.MathUtil.copysign` which is not defined here.

Comment: I grabbed it from the codename1 source: `return Double.longBitsToDouble((Double.doubleToLongBits(x) & 0x7fffffffffffffffL)
                | (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) & 0x8000000000000000L));`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your implementation of ULP takes signs and other criteria into account, when ULP returns the absolute value of the difference between the given value and the next floating point number in magnitude.

Here's an example of all you need to do; it's written in C#, but it's close enough to Java to understand.

```
public static double ULP(double value)
{
    // This is actually a constant in the same static class as this method, but 
    // we put it here for brevity of this example.
    const double MaxULP = 1.9958403095347198116563727130368E+292;

    if (Double.IsNaN(value))
    {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else if (Double.IsPositiveInfinity(value) || Double.IsNegativeInfinity(value))
    {
        return Double.PositiveInfinity;
    }
    else if (value == 0.0)
    {
        return Double.Epsilon;    // Equivalent of Double.MIN_VALUE in Java; Double.MinValue in C# is the actual minimum value a double can hold.
    }
    else if (Math.Abs(value) == Double.MaxValue)
    {
        return MaxULP;
    }

    // All you need to understand about DoubleInfo is that it's a helper struct 
    // that provides more functionality than is used here, but in this situation, 
    // we only use the `Bits` property, which is just the double converted into a 
    // long.
    DoubleInfo info = new DoubleInfo(value);

    // This is safe because we already checked for value == Double.MaxValue.
    return Math.Abs(BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(info.Bits + 1) - value);
}
```

Comment: I have to check when I'm back home, but I think that one gave false results for some non-normalized values.

Comment: @Axel Sorry, your example or mine? I'm not clear on which one you mean.

Comment: I think I remember trying exactly what you suggested, and it lead to errors.

Comment: @Axel It shouldn't; while technically a floating point standard could exist where this isn't true, for IEEE 754 and variants, adjacent floating point numbers are also adjacent integers. So calculating an adjacent integer and converting back to floating point, will give you the next representable number. The difference between the two numbers is the ULP.

Comment: Here's more information on it: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/

Comment: @Rabbit: If you are willing to share the `DoubleInfo` utility struct to sate my curiosity, I'd appreciate it. Always curious about the representation and manipulation of different numeric types.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I'd be more than glad to share. Sorry for the late reply, I'm not on here much at all anymore. The relevant source is very easy to go through and fully documented. In your case, you'll want DoubleInfo.cs and DoubleUnion.cs. Please don't judge it too harshly, the library was written as a way to really abuse computer representations of numbers to make them do things they normally shouldn't. https://bitbucket.org/RabbitB/fuzzy-logic-deprecated/src/master/

Comment: @Rabbit, I am not able to access the repo for some reason. Would you have another way to share perhaps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaheelKhan The repo was accidentally set to private. I verified it's now accessible to anyone.