# Why does (float.MaxValue / float.MinValue) evaluate to Infinity?

Tags: c#, .net, types, range, numeric

Consider the following code and results:

```
double min = (double) float.MinValue;
double max = (double) float.MaxValue;
double epsilon = (double) float.Epsilon;

double range = max - min;
double delta = range / epsilon;

Console.WriteLine ($@"Min: [{min}].");
Console.WriteLine ($@"Max: [{max}].");
Console.WriteLine ($@"Epsilon: [{epsilon}].");
Console.WriteLine ($@"Range: [{range}].");
Console.WriteLine ($@"Delta: [{delta}].");

// Results:
//  Min: [-3.4028234663852886E+38].
//  Max: [3.4028234663852886E+38].
//  Epsilon: [1.401298464324817E-45].
//  Range: [6.805646932770577E+38].
//  Delta: [4.8566719410840996E+83].
```

I was trying out some calculus, trying to get as close to `Zero (0)` as possible, and was surprised that I never thought about representing a numeric type's range before.

How would one represent a numeric type's range? In the case above, we're using `Double` to represent `Single` ranges. For `Int32`, we could use `Int64`, etc.

- How would we represent ranges for `Int64`, `Double`, and `Decimal`, etc.?
- Why does `(float.MaxValue / float.Epsilon)` evaluate to Infinity? Should it not evaluate to a number very close to, but less than `float.MaxValue`?

Comment: `float.MaxValue` is about 3e38, `float.Epsilon` is about 1e-45. The first divided by the second is going to be about 3e83, way more than 3e38, no?

Comment: @Sweeper: You are right. I was trying to calculate the smallest possible increments I could do between the ranges of `float.MinValue` and `float.MaxValue`. I hadn't realized that the division would not reveal the number of iterations that would take place.

Comment: And you can already see a more accurate result by doing the calculation in `double`s. That's your `Delta` output: 4.8566719410840996E+83. That's a way bigger number than `float.MaxValue`, hence it results in infinity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006510/density-of-floating-point-number-magnitude-of-the-number

Comment: As Hans Passant's link suggests, there is no single "smallest possible increments I could do between the ranges of float.MinValue and float.MaxValue". Rather, the smallest possible increments you could do is a function of the number from which you are incrementing. You might want to implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628950/5133585).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric types in any programming language are approximations of mathematical concepts. Since these concepts include infinities, they cannot be represented accurately in real computers.

- The range (defined as difference between the maximum and minimum value of a type) can only be represented by a type having a lager range. E.g., you could use `decimal` or [System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0) to represent the range of `Int64`. `BigInteger` could also be used to represent the range of `float` and `double` or at least the integer part of it.
- `float.MaxValue / float.Epsilon`: `float.Epsilon` is a positive number smaller than one (`public const float Epsilon = 1.401298E-45;`). If you divide a positive number by a positive number smaller than one, the result is lager than this number. E.g., 10 / 0.5 = 20. But since you cannot store a float bigger than `float.MaxValue` in a `float`, Microsoft decided to assign it `Single.PositiveInfinity` instead. They also could have decided the result should have been `Single.NaN` (Not a Number), `Single.MaxValue` or even to throw an exception. But that's how it was implemented. The `Single` type (`float` in C#`) complies with the IEC 60559:1989 (IEEE 754) standard for binary floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realized that the division would generate a value greater than what `float.MaxValue` could hold. Perhaps because this is the first time I was exploring representing ranges.